# I am reading a CSV file in datatable and then importing the same to mysql db

Tags: c#, csv

The problem is that a long number is converted to Exponential while read in datatable. For example the number 1215313371140020130606144217 is converted to 1.21531337114002E+27.

My code:

```
public static DataTable GetCSVRows(string path, bool IsFirstRowHeader)  
{
    string header = "Yes";
    string sql = string.Empty;
    string pathOnly = string.Empty;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";
        if (IsFirstRowHeader)
        {

            header = "Yes";
        }
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you read this number `1215313371140020130606144217`?

Comment: I think this is just a representation of your number. you wont miss any data, exept cases when your number is longer then can be.

Comment: yes...if it is opened with text or wordpad i can read it.

Answer (score 0):

you need update OLEDB 4.0 to [Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734),and use connection strings  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;**IMEX=1'**",attention the "IMEX=1"and you can solve it .

Comment: Thanks for your help.but the problem has not been solved yet. I am having the exception "External table is not in the expected format." for your information i am trying to read .csv file.

Comment: oh,sorry if you read a csv file ,you must use like this ""Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties="**Text**;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'",alter Extended Properties from 'Excel 8.0' to 'Text'

Comment: Thanks for your response but the result is same as it was in jet.oledb. 1215313371140020130606144217 is converted to 1.21531337114002E+27 in datatable. I have to format the csv column to 'text' before reading it to get the desired out put.